# Android CMake toolchain bug?

Tags: android, c++11, cmake

I am trying to compile the native part of my Android application using CMake.

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have this declaration:

```
append(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

`append` is my own function, defined like this:

```
function(append VAR)
  set(${VAR} ${${VAR}} ${ARGN} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

This works fine when I compile the app for other platforms, but when I add the `android.toolchain.cmake` into the mix, this line produces:

```
... -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti ;-std=c++11 ...
```

That is a `;` is for some reason added before the flag. This breaks the bash command (a call to the compiler) into two, where the first part is incomplete and the second part doesn't make sense.

How do I tell Android to use the c++11 standard?

Comment: I've never done development on Android, but you might want to look into properties like [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) instead of setting flags directly.

Comment: BTW, what's `append()`, where does it come from and what does it do? It's not a built-in CMake command.

Comment: @Angew `append()` is our own function: ```function(append VAR)
  set(${VAR} ${${VAR}} ${ARGN} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()```

Comment: I think that there is a problem with the cmake android support: even without changin CMAKE_C_FLAGS/CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in the toolchain I get ';' problems (while the code works everywhere else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `append()` function is for **appending to a list**. (CMake command `list(APPEND)` does the same). In list elements are separated with *semicolon*.

But *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* is **not a list**: it is a string of *space-separated* elements. That is why `append()` function is not applicable for that variable.

---

You code works for cases when original value of *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* is empty, so separate character is not used.